# errors installing Node and NPM on vscode for hardhat

Tags: node.js, npm, hardhat

I am trying to run hardhat on vscode on Windows for writing solidity tests. I downloaded nodejs and npm and ran npm init using the right version for hardhat) and then I tried to run npm install --save-dev hardhat and I got a ton of errors (see image) that I don't know how to resolve. Anyone know how to fix these?

One thing I noticed is that when I went to go look in the node modules folder in that directory I'm in,there was a folder called "node modules" with a subfolder "@nomicfoundation" but when I opened it, there was nothing in there.

[errors installing hardhat using npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBPCm.png)

I tried deleting nodejs and reinstalling it. I expected to not have these errors.